# Redesign handset application for tablet using Fragments

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I have a well-developed application for a phone, but I would like to add support for a tablet. The main view consists of a ListView which uses a SimpleCursorAdapter to get a list from the database. When a user taps an item, an Activity (**SPECIFIC TO THAT ID!**) is started. Some Activities share the same view, but with different information. Every activity extends FragmentAcivity. In a tablet, since I have more screen real-estate, I would like to display the ListView on the left side, and when a user taps an item, the **SPECIFIC** Activity would be shown on the left. It would mimic the image found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html) about half-way down the page. I don't have a good knowledge of Fragments, but how could I accomplish this? Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: The page you linked shows you exactly how to set it up. Is there something specific you are having trouble with? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the purposes of this answer, I will use "main activity" to refer to the one with the `ListView` and "other activities" to refer to the ones that you want to appear on the right-hand side.

Here's a thumbnail sketch:

1. Convert each of the other activities to activities whose UI is defined by a fragment.
2. Create layouts for the main activity for tablets that contain, in addition to your `ListFragment`, a `FrameLayout` container for where the other activities should go. Leave your existing layout for the main activity alone.
3. In `onListItemClick()` of your `ListFragment`, pass the event up to the main activity (e.g., `((MainActivity)getActivity()).heyDoSomething(position)`)
4. In the event handling method in the main activity (e.g., `heyDoSomething()`), see if you have the `FrameLayout`. If you do, run a `FragmentTransaction` to replace the contents of the `FrameLayout` with the appropriate fragment from the other activities. If you do not, then you are on your phone, in which case you would start up one of the other activities.

[Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/LargeScreen/EU4You) demonstrating parts of this (minus having several "other activities", so the list click just loads fresh content into an existing fragment on the right side).

Comment: Do you mean to convert each of my other activities so that they extend Fragment in your step 1? And convert my main activity into a ListFragment?

Comment: @MohitDeshpande: Well, I mean pretty much what I wrote. Your UI is presumably activities and widgets. You need to make that activities, fragments, and widgets, with the fragments managing the widgets. Basically, you move most (but not necessarily all) of your current business logic from the activity to the fragment, with the activities still there to display the fragments.

Comment: So I'd have to create a fragment for each activity and manage the UI of the activity in the fragment and only use the activity as a container?

Comment: @MohitDeshpande: Your question is worth about 28 pages in a book, which makes this all very difficult to summarize in a confined space. Your activities will still have responsibilities, orchestrating the fragments among them. Generally speaking, the activities are responsible for anything that transcends a single fragment: sending events between fragments, loading data used by multiple fragments, deciding which and how many fragments should be displayed given the screen size, and so forth.

Comment: My apologies, Fragments aren't really my thing. I would still need to create a Fragment for each of my "other activities" because there is one unique activity per database entry, correct? Then inside the Fragment, manage the widgets and inside the parent Activity, manage said Fragment.

Comment: @MohitDeshpande: "I would still need to create a Fragment for each of my "other activities" because there is one unique activity per database entry, correct?" -- I guess so. Since I don't know your code, I cannot comment authoritatively on that. "Then inside the Fragment, manage the widgets and inside the parent Activity, manage said Fragment" -- for phones, yes. For the tablet, the main activity would have the `ListFragment` (typically on the left) and would dynamically swap in other fragments (typically on the right) based upon the selected list item.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the shakespear example here : http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html

Comment: The problem with that is that I do not have one generic activity for all of my database entries. I have a separate activity for each database entry.